# REGEX with Yahoo Pipes remove &quot; front string

Tags: regex, replace, yahoo-pipes

I want this sentence:
An official "Android Device Manager" app is finally available.

To say this:
An official Android Device Manager app is finally available.

I am using regex replace `&quot;`. with null but it is giving me this:
An official ndroid Device Managerapp is finally available.

Comment: You should either post a link to your pipe itself, or at least a link to the source page. Hard to debug without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This pattern

**[("")]+**

```
MsgBox(Regex.Replace("An official ""Android Device Manager"" app", "[\("")]+", ""))
```

I tried this and it gives me like **An official Android Device Manager app**

Hope this help..

Comment: the problem is that I am working with "& quot;" without the space, not just a " mark.